# Why is this local variable labeled as undefined? - Ruby

Tags: ruby, initialization

I've got a function that goes through an array of objects, and creates a new array of objects based on certain attributes from the original array. When I run this code I get the error

> in 'nonstop': undefined local variable or method `sort_list' for main:Object (NameError)

I made sure the sort_list array was initialized outside of the loop, and I've tried initializing it with a certain size too, but I keep getting this error. I'm pretty new to ruby, so what am I doing incorrectly?

```
    def nonstop(flight_list)
      index = 0
      sort_list[] = nil
      flight_list.each do |curr|
        if (curr.depapt == ARGV[2] && curr.arrapt == ARGV[3])
          sort_list[index] = curr
          index += 1
        end
      end
      sort_list.sort! { |a,b|  a.deptime <=> b.deptime}
      sort_list.each do |curr|
         puts "#{curr.flightnum}\t#{curr.deptime}\t#{curr.arrtime}"
      end
      if (sort_list.empty?)
        puts "none"
      end
    end
```

Comment: Can you show us the code including the bit where you say you set sort_list outside the method? That might not do what you think it does

Comment: @Gareth As I read it he said 'outside of the loop'.

Comment: D'oh, I deleted my answer for nothing then!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to initialize it like this:

```
sort_list = []
```

This doesn't throw an error in `irb` for me.

Answer (score 2):

You have already got right answer.
I'll make a little refactoring, which can be useful for novice.

```
def nonstop(flight_list)
  sort_list = flight_list.select { |curr| curr.depapt == ARGV[2] && curr.arrapt == ARGV[3] }
  sort_list.sort_by! &:deptime
  sort_list.each do |curr|
    puts "#{curr.flightnum}\t#{curr.deptime}\t#{curr.arrtime}"
  end
  puts "none" if sort_list.empty?
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is why `sort_list[] = nil` does not work in ruby:

`[]` On its own is a shortcut for `Array.new`

`[]` after a variable name is calling `[]` on the variable.  So in that context `[]` is a method.

sort_list is not set to anything, so it is undefined.  So `sort_list[]` is calling `[]` on an undefined value

Setting any variable to nil makes it of nil class.